# Asp.net core - dotnet test not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

I have an asp.net core application and i want to do some x-unit testing on it. However, when i run my tests i get

```
dotnet test
No executable found matching command "dotnet-test-"
```

How do i configure x-unit properly ?

Project.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "xunit": "2.1.0",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "1.0.0-rc2-build10025"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot the `testRunner` property:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-*",
    "xunit": "2.2.0-*"
  },
  ...
  "testRunner": "xunit"
}
```

Comment: In dependencies , or where ? Also, off topic but i recognize you from your github posts about this subject, lol small world .

Comment: Hehe, small world. In project.json as a top level property. Here's a sample test project: https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Test/project.json

Comment: Okay, i have to wait 6 minutes, but this is correct. Thanks